# Not able to add event handler in dropzone

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am making this addDropzone() function called on a button click which passes a value as mutilple dropzone elements are needed, but only one at time but on different div's so 'val' parameter in function helps define div id's. I am able to run the dropzone element. It also saves the files on the server, but i am not able to get event handler's working.

This is the function that I am using.

Also if anybody could suggest me a way to read server message in event handler

### JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
    function addDropzone(val){
    document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = '<div class="item" style="width:96%; margin:5px auto; position:relative; height: auto; background-color:lightgray;"><form action="file-upload.php" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone-'+val+'"></form></div>';        
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div #my-dropzone-"+val);     
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
            paramName: 'file',
            method: 'post',
            maxFiles: 1,
            url: 'file-upload.php',
            dictDefaultMessage: "Drag your images",
            clickable: false,
            maxFilesize: 512,
            uploadMultiple: false,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            forceFallback:true      
    };
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = false;
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone.enable();

    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        init: function(){
        this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) { alert("File limit 1"); });
        this.on("complete", function(file) {alert(serverReponse);});
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't know about dropzone, but as I understand the documentation, I would have written it like this :

```
function addDropzone(val){
  var dropZoneId= "my-dropzone-"+val;
  // this line has moved-up, and the option is not referenced in the same way
  Dropzone.options[dropZoneId] = false;
  // proper way of adding new content to div2 without losing event handlers
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<div class="item" style="width:96%; margin:5px auto; position:relative; height: auto; background-color:lightgray;"><form action="file-upload.php" class="dropzone" id="'+dropZoneId+'"></form></div>';
  document.getElementById("div2").appendChild(div.firstChild);           
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#"+dropZoneId,{
        paramName: 'file',
        method: 'post',
        maxFiles: 1,
        url: 'file-upload.php',
        dictDefaultMessage: "Drag your images for zone "+val,
        clickable: false,
        maxFilesize: 512,
        uploadMultiple: false,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        forceFallback:false,
        init: function(){
           // from the doc, quick debug
           this.on("addedfile", function(file) { alert("added file in zone."+val); });
           this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) { alert("File limit 1"); });
           this.on("complete", function(file) {alert(serverReponse);});
           }
        });      
}
$(document).ready(function(){
     addDropzone(1);
     addDropzone(2);
    }
   );
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but the code still remains the same. you included the init:function() within the .options class.. but its still not working in case of dynamic addition. when I do the same on static version if goes fine. I wonder if its the placement of Jquery code which is not letting it to work

Comment: @Parminder you should watch more closely. The code does not remain the same. Have you tried this exact code ? I edited and pointed the differences. The main point being in the way the option is referenced : `Dropzone.options[dropZoneId]`  instead of `Dropzone.options.myDropzone` (which does not use `val` at all)

Comment: yes, now I just tried the exact same way.. it is doing everything (uploading the files and saving them also) but not acknowledging the events..

Comment: what do you refer to as a+= instead of a=? ... are you referring to the innerHTML portion(innerHTML += '<div>';  this way..

Comment: @Parminder came to something which works. Edited my answer and see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/svNXE/

Comment: thanks jbl for your kind effort.. I tried this very example on fiddle but i didnt got any result on my end. Idk what the problem is. Anyhow I decided to change the logic a bit now I am using a defined dropbox area(not dynamic anymore) on my page and then using events for the other result..

Comment: @Parminder might be a browser issue. Which one are(s) you using ? (FF25 and Chrome31 for my part) Disappointing that this component does not seem that reliable...

Comment: Ooops.. I actually meant that fiddle example worked but it gave no result when I added to my code. It looks like I am not able to understand the concept properly at this stage.. I use FF 25 too..